# How do I force Rails to use my cache instead of always going to the database?

Tags: caching, model, ruby-on-rails-5, finder, in-memory

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this model

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  belongs_to :distance_unit
```

and I notice when I have a line like below

```
distance = Distance.new({:distance => my_obj.distance, :distance_unit => my_obj.distance_unit})
```

it causes the following to be executed

```
SELECT  "distance_units".* FROM "distance_units" WHERE "distance_units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Nothing unusual, but I have a cached method created in my DistanceUnit model

```
class DistanceUnit < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.cached_find_by_id(id)
    Rails.cache.fetch("distanceunit-#{id}") do
      puts "looking for id: #{id}"
      find_by_id(id)
    end
  end
```

and I would like the "distance = Distance.new({:distance => my_obj.distance, :distance_unit => my_obj.distance_unit})" line to invoke my cached functionality instead of running off to the database.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: what are you using for storing the cache?

Comment: Oh good question.  I have "config.cache_store = :memory_store" in my config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to my comment, note that the memory_store is only used within a process, so each process will have its own store (consider `MemCacheStore` if that is an issue). Also the cache is gone when the process ends.

As a general note: The `belongs_to` association inherently triggers a lookup *if the object hasn't been fetched yet*. There are plenty of caches built in the Rails framework and in general I wouldn't worry too much about premature optimization in the beginning (and only optimize when you find queries are running too slow).

Also: Accessing the cache is also a call to a type of database, and an lookup based on an probably indexed id typically isn't really a heavy call. Also if there's just a few distance units, you maybe simply using a constant could work?

But to answer your question. There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that says `cached_find_by_id` (and while rails does a lot of things automagically, this isn't one of them).

You could create the following method in `MyObject` that overrides the 'getter' that is created by the `belongs_to` association:

```
def distance_unit
  DistanceUnit.cached_find_by_id(distance_unit_id)
end
```

However, if you're simply initializing an ActiveRecord object and you *don't need the DistanceUnit in this call* you could also pass the id directly, since that is what is stored in the database.

```
Distance.new({:distance => my_obj.distance, :distance_unit_id => my_obj.distance_unit_id})
```